# Small gap to right of HTML pages - Is this a bug or just a quirk of web browsers?

Tags: html, css

There is a small gap between webpages and the browser window. It can be seen by increasing the zoom and looking at a colored  on the right of the screen.

It appears on my website project here:

[image: Small gap between webpage and browser window]

It also shows up [blender.org](https://www.blender.org/), [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/) and even here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

I did not expect to see this here.
Is this a bug or just a quirk of web browsers?

**Additional**

To help better describe the issue:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
background-color: red;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

div{
background-color: blue;
height: 200 px;
width: 100%;
)
```

By zooming in to 500% and moving all the way to the right, the red background of the body can be seen.

[image: Red background seen behind blue div]

Answer (score -1):

It maybe because of the default margin of body tag which is 8px by default.
You can Solve this by setting body's margin to 0px in css.
Also if you want, you can set padding also to 0px for more control on sizing.